# How to get the number of elements using Optional

Tags: spring-mvc

Get the number of elements in `List` using `size()` method but how to get number of elements using `Optional<entityname>`.

In List:

```
List<User> data = this.Service.getUserById(id);
System.out.print(data.size());
```

In Optional:

```
Optional<User> data = this.Service.getUserById(id);
System.out.print(); // how to get in Optional
```

Comment: It's either 1 or 0. It's not a list, it's a single `User` that may or may not be present.

Comment: Not with `Optional`s. If that method returns an `Optional<User>` it's meant to return a single `User` or nothing. No way around it. If you want a method that returns more than one thing it should return a `List` or (if you're using spring data) a `Page`. *(now it looks like I'm talking to myself, but there was a comment by OP asking how to count elements in an `Optional`, which they then deleted, but I'm leaving this here anyway)*

Comment: I am sorry, @FedericoklezCulloca

Answer (score 0):

An `Optional<User>` is not a list, what you are getting back is MAYBE a single user, or not, and it is your job to check if it returned a SINGLE user or not. The optional contains a `User` not a `List<User>`

If you want to get the user if it was returned, there are several ways.

This is one way, to get the user but is just an example code and should not be used in any production scenario as it is more verbose than it needs to be and is here to explain the general idea. but as mentioned there are several other ways in the link in the end of the post.

```
// This line returns maybe a single user, not a list of users.
Optional<User> data = this.Service.getUserById(id);
if(data.isPresent()) {
    final User user = data.get(); 
}
```

You can read more about using optionals here:

[Java Optionals](https://www.baeldung.com/java-optional)

Comment: Generally using `isPresent` is considered an antipattern. Instead use `orElseGet` or `orElseThrow`.

Comment: and as i mentioned, there are several ways, i did not in any way say that this was the pattern to use. Which you seem to think. As the user is a complete beginner, this example is the easiest and most straight forward to understand.

Comment: @M.Deinum  Can you tell me how to get data from database and count total data. In java we use `resultset.last()` but what in spring boot

Comment: Spring Boot is Java... So your question doesn't really make sense. I suggest to readup on what you are using (in this case Spring Boot. In your case advising on what to use is impossible as we don't know what `this.service` is or how it is implemented.

Comment: @Toerktumlare the problem with dumbed down advices is that people to tend to stick with them. So if one gives advice one should give the best practice imho.

Comment: @M.Deinum or at least point out that this is a simplified example and not meant to indicate a best practice.

Comment: @M.Deinum `service` is `@Autowired` in controller

Comment: the question is not "what are the best practices when using optionals in java", so what the code example looks like is besides the point. The example is to point out that what you get from the Optional is a single user, and that what is in the optional is a single user and not a list. I highly doubt that someone will read this answer and copy the above code. And when you can point out that someone did it, then i will exclude it. The code is to show a simple point of proving my statement, that the optional contains a single User, and not a List

Comment: also, functional vs imperative programming paradigm, has nothing to do with what is good vs bad code. Some ppl prefer the functional approach, some prefer the imperative. As long as someone can't provide a NON-opinion-based reason, then the example stands, as the example only is there to show that the optional contains a single user and not a list.

Answer (score 0):

You need to think that your list (`data`) is inside `Optional`. So you need to convert (`map`) this list to size of this list, and return value (using e.g orElseGet) or return 0 is list is null.
You could try something like this:

```
Optional<User> data = this.Service.getUserById(id);
int size = data .map(List::size).orElseGet(() -> Integer.valueOf(0)).intValue();
// or int size = data .map(List::size).orElse(0);
```

Comment: But inside the `Optional` is a `User`, not a `List`, so how can you map it with `List::size`?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. You was having ```List<User> data = this.Service.getUserById(id);``` so this is why I was thinking that you revicere list. ```Optional``` is <0, 1> and list is <0, infinity>. To check if something was found, you need to use ```isPresent```. If you will have list inside ```Optional<List<User>>``` then my solution will work. Why in your example function ```getUserById``` return list?